# How to group by key and only return observation by max from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How does one return all observations from a dataframe that only hold the max value for each unique key associated?  I tried groupby and max but for every difference I get more than on value per key returned back.  See example below:

```
import pandas as pd
key = [111,111,222,333,444,555]
flag = [0,1,1,1,1,1]
date = [pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01'),pd.to_datetime('2020-01-02'), 
        pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01'),pd.to_datetime('2020-04-01'),
        pd.to_datetime('2020-03-01'),pd.to_datetime('2020-05-01')]

df_dic = {'key':key, 'flag':flag, 'date':date}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dic)
df
df.groupby(['key', 'flag']).agg({'date':'max'}).reset_index()
```

This returns:

```
key  flag       date
0  111     0 2020-01-01
1  111     1 2020-01-02
2  222     1 2020-02-01
3  333     1 2020-04-01
```

I want to return only the observations with the max date per unique key like so:

```
key  flag       date
0  111     1 2020-01-02
1  222     1 2020-02-01
2  333     1 2020-04-01
```

Comment: What happened to key 444 and 555?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can avoid `groupby` and use `sort_values` and `drop_dplicates`.

```
print(df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('key', keep='last'))
   key  flag       date
1  111     1 2020-01-02
2  222     1 2020-02-01
4  444     1 2020-03-01
3  333     1 2020-04-01
5  555     1 2020-05-01
```

Note that you can add the key column in the `sort_values` if the order matters to you in the result `df.sort_values(['key', 'date'])...`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (although maybe not the best one) is to use an inner join after the `groupby` method. This ensures that the flags are taken from the original dataframe, either they are 0 or 1.

```
df.groupby(['key'])\
    .agg({'date': 'max'})\
    .reset_index()\
    .merge(df, how='inner', on=['key', 'date'])

#    key       date  flag
# 0  111 2020-01-02     1
# 1  222 2020-02-01     1
# 2  333 2020-04-01     1
# 3  444 2020-03-01     1
# 4  555 2020-05-01     1
```